# JSP Access to Javabean Properties

Tags: java, jsp, properties, el

I have a Java class with a method, hasMoreParameters().

In JSP, I want to get the property:

${holder.moreParameters}

How do I do this?

Answer (score 6):

You **can not** access holder.hasMoreParameters() as you have specified:

```
${holder.moreParameters}
```

This is because the **${bean.property}** syntax only works with methods that follow [JavaBean getter/setter naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html).  This means the property's accessor method **must** start with '**get**'.  There is only one exception to this rule: if the method returns a boolean value, the method is allowed to start with '**is**'.

If, as in your case, the method name does not meet these criteria, you must find some other way to access the data, such as passing the value in a request attribute, or renaming the method.